# Print multiple images

Tags: c#, .net, printing

I need to print a large image collection of pictures.

If I use something like:

```
printDocument.PrintPage += OnPrintPage;
printDocument.Print();
```

my printing task size in printer queue takes more than 1 GB!

Can anyone suggest how can I print the images one by one. Maybe some event like PrintJobIsFinished is available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you can use the NumberOfJobs property on the PrintQueue class to determine if there are any jobs in the queue.  You will need to poll the printer until NumberOfJobs drops to 0, and then kick off the next print job.